# Sending SMTP Mail from ASP.NET From ME to ME

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, email, smtp

I am trying to add a user suggestions interface to my MVC4 application using system.net.mail .

I want to use my own email address to send mail from me to me with their suggestions. This works fine on debug, but when I publish to a server, Google sends me an email saying I might be a victim blah blah...

Is this just a Gmail thing, or is there a better way to send SMTP mail?

Comment: Are you using ASP Classic (.asp extension), or ASP.NET?

Comment: Then please do not use the [tag:asp-classic] tag.

Comment: sorry, typed asp. didn't realise it added the -classic part.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail uses specific algorithms and other relative data to mark a email as spam. In short your email has to have a valid and verified email sender address, authenticated request, etc.

You can check the details of GMail spam detection policy here -

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en

Comment: Depends, because this could be a result of a lot of reasons, first check all the reasons for Gmail Spam detection that you are not doing any of them. This way you can make sure that the problem is in the coding side.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you for your help! Anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

we used to use the .net mailer, but now we use mandrill (http://mandrill.com/)

its free for up a certain volume, and certainly for development it serves it purpose without the headaches of the gmail think it's spam, phished emails and what not.

here's a .net wrapper: https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet